# Run code while splashscreen is displaying

Tags: java, android, android-studio, background, task

I have an app that goes out and gets the time from the internet. Does some maths on it and then after that is done it starts another activity.

Here is the code in my splashscreen activity

```
package com.firefluxentertainment.retroclicker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    long endTime;
    long timeDelta;
    Long endTimeMaths;
    long timeStamp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        load();


        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;

        try {

            result = task.execute("http://www.currenttimestamp.com/").get();

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("current_time = (.*?);");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
            m.find();
            String unixTime = (m.group(1));
            timeStamp = Integer.parseInt(unixTime);
            endTimeMaths = endTime/1000;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "you aint got no internet man", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        timeDelta = timeStamp-endTimeMaths;

        Log.i("TimeDelta", timeDelta+"");

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }.start();
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    void save(){
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("TEST_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putLong("endTime", endTime);
        editor.commit();
    }

    void load() {
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("TEST_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        endTime = pref.getLong("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

I have the webpage content containing the time download in the background and then i run a pattern and matcher on it. The problem is that most of the time is being wasted running the matcher rather than downloading the webpage. Since the matcher is running on the main thread it is delaying the UI thread causing the logo that i have set in the splashscreen layout not to display until the matcher is finished. How would I make it so that the matcher runs in the background as well so that the UI is not delayed?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Remove `.get()` from `task.execute` and also do all `Pattern matching` inside `onPostExecute` method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK .get() converts it to a string so it can be matched. Removing .get sends an arbitrary async variable type that cannot be indexed by a matcher

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the `AsyncTask` will run as long as the `Activity` is alive. To decouple it from the `Activity` you have a couple options:

1. The best thing to do is probably sent an `Intent` to an `IntentService` that handles this. You will need to persist the results (like in `SharedPrefs`) and/or create a binder/callback or use other methods to get the data.
2. Put the `AsyncTask` in your `Application` class. This is not really a great idea because it is not the purpose of that class, but it would work.
3. In the splashscreen, only make the call to get the data, then pass it in an intent to the next `Activity` - and in that `Activity` run the `AsyncTask` to do the pattern matching. This breaks up the processing, but probably will result in the user waiting for these calls on both screens. Still, it would be better to see the app "doing something" rather than having a very long wait.

There are other ways to handle this, but these are probably the best approaches without getting too complex.